# How can I make a button remain in its focus state after clicking elsewhere?

Tags: html, css, button

I'm trying to create a page with a row of search filter buttons that always has one selected. The problem I'm facing is that if the mouse is clicked elsewhere on the page, the visibly selected button reverts to its default state and the user can no longer see which search filter is being applied. I'm using the css focus property, and maybe this is part of the problem, but I don't know how else to achieve what I want. Here's the relevant code:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .filters-group-wrap {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
}

.btn {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 130px;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  color: #888888;
  font-size: 1em;
  transition: .2s ease-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  font-size: .8em;
}

@media (-moz-touch-enabled:0),(pointer: fine) {
  .btn:hover {
    color:#CCCCCC;
      }
}

.btn:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 4px 1px rgba(75,75,75,1);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .btn {
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="filter-options" data-toggle="buttons">
  <button id="showA" class="btn" data-group="groupA" style="background-image: url('A.jpg')">A</button>
  <button id="showB" class="btn" data-group="groupB" style="background-image: url('B.jpg')">B</button>
  <button id="showC" class="btn" data-group="groupC" style="background-image: url('C.jpg')">C</button>
</div>
```

I'm using Bootstrap, so jQuery solutions are okay, although my understanding is limited. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't do that with plain CSS. You'll need JavaScript for this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions everybody. I was able to learn enough to get it working. For some reason, the class 'active' was an issue and I had to assign the function to 'button' to get it working. I don't know why, but it works now, so I'm not questioning it!

```js
$("button").click(function(){
   $("button").removeClass("pressed");
   $(this).addClass("pressed");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of working with the focus property, maybe you could use jquery to assign an "active" class to the button when is clicked.
If user clicks anywhere, the button remains active.

Check the code below

```
$(".btn").click(function(){ // when any button is clicked
   $(".btn").removeClass("active"); //delete all "active" classes from all buttons
   $(this).addClass("active"); //assign the "active" class only to the one that was clicked
   return false;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This didn't quite work for me but I was able to modify it to work perfectly (see my answer). Thanks heaps, you saved the day.

Comment: I'm glad it helps. If you consider my answer was helpful to solve your problem, click the check icon.

Answer (score 0):

The focus state works with the browser in a way you described above but you can try this using jquery or pure JS.

Define a css class that hold your desired focus state and the toggle the class on the child buttons of class filter-options.

Would like to here from you in case.

Answer (score 0):

```
   .active {
     background: yellow;
     border: 1px solid black;
     outline-style: solid;
     outline-color: red;
     outline-width: thin;
    }



    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      .filters-group-wrap {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }
    }

    .btn {
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      background-size: cover;
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 30px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
      -moz-border-radius: 30px;
      padding: 0px;
      padding-top: 5px;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 130px;
      margin: 10px;
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 35px;
      color: #888888;
      font-size: 1em;
      transition: .2s ease-out;
      cursor: pointer;
      border: none;
      font-size: .8em;
    }

    @media (-moz-touch-enabled:0),(pointer: fine) {
      .btn:hover {
        color:#CCCCCC;
          }
    }

    .btn:focus {
      outline: none;
      box-shadow: 2px 1px 4px 1px rgba(75,75,75,1);
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .btn {
      }
    }
    <div class="filter-options" data-toggle="buttons">
      <button id="showA" class="btn" data-group="groupA" style="background-image: url('A.jpg')">A</button>
      <button id="showB" class="btn" data-group="groupB" style="background-image: url('B.jpg')">B</button>
      <button id="showC" class="btn" data-group="groupC" style="background-image: url('C.jpg')">C</button>
    </div>




$("btn").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
</script>
```